# What is the derivation for shot noise current?

Tags: current, noise, communication, charge, bandwidth

[image]

The screenshot is taken from
Principles of Electronic Communications
by Louis E. Frenzel Jr.

I don't know where the formula came from and I tried searching, but couldn't seem to find any that I understand.

Comment: [This paper](http://www.pas.rochester.edu/~dmw/ast203/Lectures/Lect_19.pdf) would help.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I independently found the same paper LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a derivation of this here:

[Shot Noise Derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_noise)

the relevant part:

[image: Shot noise derivation]

Comment: Could you elaborate the Poison process part if you are familiar with it? I get that it is like that but I'm not familiar with it myself. Especially that I only see a root and not a square. I assume one of the quantities represents a mean.

Comment: Poisson is a standard in probability and statistics.  You can find references to that just about anywhere.

Comment: I mean at least explain why those variables are analogs to the concept used in Poisson, if possible.